# What syntax to use for parsing {{ from_dttm }} and {{ to_dttm }} Jinja variables as datetime objects in Custom SQL queries?

Tags: postgresql, jinja2, apache-superset

**Question:** How to correctly format `{{ from_dttm }}` and `{{ to_dttm }}` [default Jinja variables](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/sql-templating/) so that they are parsed as `datetime` objects in Apache Superset Custom SQL metrics?

---

**MWE:** Say I want to show what is the time range covered by the data I use in my dashboards — what can be affected by the Time Range filter.
I use the `public.birth_names` demo dataset for the sake of the example.

So I create a BigNumber chart, with the following custom Metric:

```
age(
  {% if from_dttm is not none %}
     '{{ from_dttm }}'
  {% else %}
    min(ds)
  {% endif %}
,
  {% if to_dttm is not none %}
    '{{ to_dttm }}'
  {% else %}
    max(ds)
  {% endif %}
)
```

However, if I format the Jinja variables as:

- `{{ from_dttm }}`, I get:

```
Error: syntax error at or near "{" 
LINE 1: SELECT age({{ from_dttm }} , '{{ to_dttm }}') AS "age(
```

- `'{{ from_dttm }}'`, I get

```
Error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "{{ from_dttm }}" 
LINE 1: SELECT age('{{ from_dttm }}'
```

- `"{{ from_dttm }}"`, I get

```
Error: column "{{ from_dttm }}" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT age("{{ from_dttm }}" ,
```

---

I'm using Superset at [`5ae7e5499`](https://github.com/apache/superset/commit/5ae7e5499966c9e01d5e42a61edf1ce94dd346fa) (Latest commit on Mar 25, 2022), with PostgreSQL as back-end db engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After offline discussion with [@villebro](https://github.com/villebro), it turns out that:

- `'{{ from_dttm }}'` is the valid syntax — one can try with a simpler example: `MIN('{{ from_dttm }}')`: this works, whereas both other syntaxes yield an error.
- however, there is still a bug in current (version `1.4.*`) versions, where `{{ from_dttm }}` is not rendered (what caused `AGE()` to yield an error in the particular example above). This issue has been raised in [#19564](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/19564), and a fix submitted in [#19565](https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/19565).